# Unable to Initialize Magnific Popup LIghtbox

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, magnific-popup

I'm trying to use the Magnific Popup plug in my website, but I can't seem to be able to initialize it. I've added the necessary mark-up classes, CSS, initialization code, and referenced the JS and CSS files, but no luck.

In my site, I'm not calling jQuery again since it's included with Bootstrap. My browser console says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function`.

Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#test-popup" class="portfolio-box open-popup-link">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Title
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Click to View
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
                Popup content
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<script>
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  midClick: true
});
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mw6ahLzz/1/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you reference magnific and jquery libraries?

Comment: I downloaded these (https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/tree/master/dist) files and uploaded to my server, however in the Fiddle, I referenced some files that I saw in another (working) Fiddle with Magnific. More specifically, I have the <link> and <script> tags in the <head> section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the jQuery library before any Js library,

so

First comes jQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then comes magnific popup library

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.magnific-popup/0.9.9/magnific-popup.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.magnific-popup/0.9.9/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```

Initialize the pop-up script and make it Dom-ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
      type:'inline',
      midClick: true
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <a href="#test-popup" class="portfolio-box open-popup-link">
                <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                        <div class="project-name">
                            Title
                        </div>
                        <div class="project-category text-faded">
                            Click to View
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
            Popup content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tqo59nd/)

Comment: That makes sense. Part of the issue was also where I was calling Bootstrap's default jQuery library. Thanks!